# FragmentActivity and ListView

Tags: android

My main activity collects LatLng data from server and finds some cities distances using google maps. Because of that it extends FragmentActivity. I want also to show the results using a ListView. The problem is that FragmentActivity doesn't support adapter. Any ideas to deal with that given that i'm not an expert...

My code

```
package com.example.tranfer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;



public class CheckItineraries extends FragmentActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String username , origin_lat ,origin_lng ,destination_lat ,destination_lng ,
    waypoint1_lat ,waypoint1_lng ,waypoint2_lat ,waypoint2_lng ,waypoints;
    int i, j ,b;

    ListView list;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.2:80/etruck1/check_itineraries.php";

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

    // JSON Node names

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();



    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itinList;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.checkitineraries);

        itinList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new GetData().execute();
    }

    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Log.d("meg", "meg");

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CheckItineraries.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Καταχωρώ τα στοιχεία...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            username = settings.getString("username", "nikos");

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray itin_results = json.getJSONArray("itin_results");

                for (int i = 0; i < itin_results.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = itin_results.getJSONObject(i);

                    String username = c.getString("username");
                    String startPoliPro = c.getString("startPoliPro");
                    String start_lat_pro = c.getString("start_lat_pro");
                    String start_lng_pro = c.getString("start_lng_pro");
                    String finalPoliPro = c.getString("finalPoliPro");
                    String final_lat_pro = c.getString("final_lat_pro");
                    String final_lng_pro = c.getString("final_lng_pro");

                    LinkedHashMap<String, String> pinakas = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    pinakas.put("username", username);
                    pinakas.put("startPoliPro", startPoliPro);
                    pinakas.put("start_lat_pro", start_lat_pro);
                    pinakas.put("start_lng_pro", start_lng_pro);
                    pinakas.put("finalPoliPro", finalPoliPro);
                    pinakas.put("final_lat_pro", final_lat_pro);
                    pinakas.put("final_lng_pro", final_lng_pro);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    itinList.add(pinakas);
                    b = itin_results.length();
                    Log.d("b", String.valueOf(b));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            //list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(CheckItineraries.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line



            origin_lat = itinList.get(0).get("start_lat_pro").toString();
            origin_lng = itinList.get(0).get("start_lng_pro").toString();   
            destination_lat = itinList.get(0).get("final_lat_pro").toString();
            destination_lng = itinList.get(0).get("final_lng_pro").toString();

            for (i = 0; i <b; i++) {                
                markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

                Log.d("panikos", itinList.get(i).get("username").toString());
                Log.d("panikos", itinList.get(i).get("startPoliPro").toString());
                Log.d("panikos", itinList.get(i).get("start_lat_pro").toString());
                Log.d("panikos", itinList.get(i).get("start_lng_pro").toString());
                Log.d("panikos", itinList.get(i).get("finalPoliPro").toString());
                Log.d("panikos", itinList.get(i).get("final_lat_pro").toString());
                Log.d("panikos", itinList.get(i).get("final_lng_pro").toString());

            waypoint1_lat = itinList.get(i).get("start_lat_pro").toString();
            waypoint1_lng = itinList.get(i).get("start_lng_pro").toString();
            waypoint2_lat = itinList.get(i).get("final_lat_pro").toString();
            waypoint2_lng = itinList.get(i).get("final_lng_pro").toString();

            LatLng origin1 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(origin_lat), Double.parseDouble(origin_lng));
            LatLng destination = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(destination_lat), Double.parseDouble(destination_lng));
            LatLng waypoint1 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(waypoint1_lat), Double.parseDouble(waypoint1_lng));
            LatLng waypoint2 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(waypoint2_lat), Double.parseDouble(waypoint2_lng));

            Log.d("origin1", origin1.toString());
            Log.d("destination", destination.toString());
            Log.d("waypoint1", waypoint1.toString());
            Log.d("waypoint2", waypoint2.toString());


            markerPoints.add(origin1);
            markerPoints.add(destination);
            markerPoints.add(waypoint1);
            markerPoints.add(waypoint2);


                LatLng or = markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                Log.d("ena", markerPoints.get(0).toString());
                Log.d("dyo", markerPoints.get(1).toString());
                Log.d("tria", markerPoints.get(2).toString());
                Log.d("tessera", markerPoints.get(3).toString());


                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(or, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                downloadTask.execute(url);

            }
        }


        private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng or, LatLng dest) {

            // Origin of route
            String str_origin = "origin=" + or.latitude + ","+ or.longitude;

            // Destination of route
            String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Waypoints
            LatLng way1 = markerPoints.get(2);
            LatLng way2 = markerPoints.get(3);

            Log.d("way1", way1.toString());
            Log.d("way2", way2.toString());

            // Waypoints
             waypoints = "";
            for(int i=2;i<markerPoints.size();i++){
                LatLng point  = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(i);
                if(i==2) 
                    waypoints = "waypoints=";

                waypoints += point.latitude + "," + point.longitude + "|";

            }

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor +"&"+waypoints;


            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                    + output + "?" + parameters;

            return url;
        }

        private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        iStream));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
            } finally {
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return data;
        }
    ///
        // Fetches data from url passed
        ////
        private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            // Downloading data in non-ui thread
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

                // For storing data from web service
                String data = "";

                try {
                    // Fetching the data from web service
                    data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
                }
                return data;
            }

            // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
            // doInBackground()
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

                // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
                parserTask.execute(result);

            }
        }

        //e
        public class ParserTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser1 parser = new DirectionsJSONParser1();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);

            Log.d("json", jObject.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override

    //o
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        String distance = "";
        String duration = "";


        Log.d("result", String.valueOf(result.size()));

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j); 

                if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                    distance = point.get("distance");
                    continue;
                }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                    duration = point.get("duration");
                    continue;
                }   

            Log.d("lat", String.valueOf(point.get("lat")));
                Log.d("lng", String.valueOf(point.get("lng")));

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        CheckItineraries.this, itinList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "startpoli1", "finalpoli1"}, 
                        new int[] { R.id.startpoli,  R.id.finalpoli });

                **setListAdapter(adapter);**
            }

        }
if(distance!=null){
        Log.d("finito", distance);
}

    }




}


        }       
    }
```

Eclipse says " The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type CheckItineraries.GetData.ParserTask"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setListAdapter()` ia a method in `ListActivity` but your activity is not a `ListActivity` but a `FragmentActivity`.

You can achieve the same by obtaining a reference to the `ListView` in your content view layout with `findViewById()` like you do elsewhere in your code, and then call `setAdapter()` on the `ListView` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create listview adaptor  from context.

```
listViewAdapter = new ListView_Adapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

A FragmentActivity and Adapter is two somethings diferents.

**[FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)**

> Base class for activities that want to use the support-based Fragment and Loader APIs.

**[Adapter official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)**

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

You can use one adapter in your ListView.

**EDIT POST:**

You are creating a ArrayAdapter and you have a String object ArrayAdapter.

```
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CheckItineraries.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1,line);
```

Comment: when i'm trying to use setadaptor method, eclipse says that i have to create it

Comment: pless paste code for I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just have my Activities extend Activity and I use Fragments in my activity which extend ListFragment. From the docs:

> ListFragment hosts a ListView object that can be bound to different data sources, typically either an array or a Cursor holding query results.